# Categorize already written tests into categories like long running, security related etc in python

Tags: python

Can someone help me how to categorize tests in python?

Let me explain my scenario. I have a set of tests, `test_1.py`, `test_2.py`, ... `test_n.py`, which perform tests on different functions.

Now I would like to categorize them based on the functions they perform like Security related tests (SSL) into one category and long running tests into different category etc...

So that I'll be able to run only a single category of tests (when anything related to that particular functionality changes) rather than all the tests.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try python unittest library , very comprehensive and solves all your problems.

Comment: It would help to tell how you're actually writing your tests now.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to categorize using unittest library.